# Search values in a Pandas DataFrame with values from another DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes.

**df_dora**

|  | content | feature | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cyber hygien | risk management | 1 |
| 2 | cyber risk | risk management | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... ... |  |
| 59 | intellig share | information sharing | 63 |
| 60 | inform share | information sharing | 64 |

**df_corpus**

|  | content | id | meta.name | meta._split_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | market grow cyber attack... | 56a2a2e28954537131a4aa734f49e361 | 14_Group_AG_2021 | 0 |
| 1 | sec form file index | 7aedfd4df02687d3dff9897c925da508 | 14_Group_AG_2021 | 1 |
|  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 213769 | cyber secur alert parent compani fina... | ab10325601597f203f3f0af7aa647112 | 17_La_Banque_2021 | 8581 |
| 213770 | intellig share statement parent compani fina... | 6af5687ac31849d19d2048e0b2ca472d | 17_La_Banque_2021 | 8582 |

I am trying to extract a count of each term listed in df_dora.content within df_corpus.content grouped by df_content.meta.name.
I tried to use isin

`df = df_corpus[df_corpus.content.isin(df_dora.content)]`

`len(df)`

Returns only 17 rows

|  | content | id | meta.name | meta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41474 | incid | a4c478e0fad1b9775c05e01d871b3aaf | 3_Agricole_2021 | 10185 |
| 68690 | oper risk | 2e5139d82c242c89523110cc1110647a | 10_Banking_Group_PLC_2021 | 5525 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 99259 | risk report | a84eefb9a4772d13eb67f2d6ae5215cb | 31_Building_Society_2021 | 4820 |
| 105662 | risk manag | e8050be841fedb6dd10599e8b4892a9f | 43_Bank_SA_2021 | 131 |

`df_corpus.loc[df_corpus.content.isin(df_dora.content), 'content'].tolist()`

also returns 17 rows

if I search for 2 of the terms that exist in df_dora directly in df_corpus
`resiliency_term = df_corpus.loc[df_corpus['content'].str.contains("cyber risk|inform share", case=False)]`

`print(resiliency_term)`

I get 243 rows (which matches what was in the original file.)

So given the above...my question is this how do I extract a count of each term listed in df_dora.content within df_corpus.content grouped by df_content.meta.name.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unique_vals = '|'.join(df_dora.content.unique())
df_corpus.groupby('meta.name').apply(lambda x: x.content.str.findall(unique_vals).explode().value_counts())
```

Output given your four lines of each:

```
17_La_Banque_2021  intellig share    1
Name: content, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That worked a charm. Thanks so much for taking the time to help with this.

Comment: @BeRT2me...might be pushing it but I am struggling to try and roll the counts of the output up to the associated feature, e,g  cyber threat, cybersecur, data protect all are associated to the df_dora.feature - 'risk management'. Is there a way of calculating the totals by feature?

Comment: Instead of `apply` you might try `transform`, that might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: threw an error 'Series' object has no attribute 'content'. I will see if I can get it to work.

Comment: No luck.....can't seem to figure it out. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd advise starting a new question and providing as much information as possible there about what you're trying to do~